# Creating an Array of Vector Pointers

Tags: c++, vector, dynamic, polymorphism

I have to input a number "N" and create an array of vector pointers so that by using Polymorphism I am able to place different objects at different indexes of the vector.
What I'm trying to do:

```
vector<Vehicle> *ptr(N);
```

This gives an error, how can I create an array of vector pointers of type ?

Comment: Are you sure you want an array of vector pointers? Isn't what you actually want a vector of pointers to object of `Vehicle`?

Comment: What I wanted was an array of vector pointers of type Vehicle (which is the parent class). I needed to use polymorphism to create child objects and place different objects at different indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard C++ doesn't support Variable-Length Array (VLA), so you should create a vector of vector pointors instead.

```
std::vector<vector<Vehicle> *> ptr(N);
```

If your compiler supports VLA and you want to use that for some reason, you should use `[]` instead of `()`.

```
vector<Vehicle> *ptr[N];
```